# Is an object creating using an "inline" new statement automatically disposed?

Tags: c#

The following snippet is taken from an example of `ComboBox::DrawItem` implementation on [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(animalColor), rectangle);
```

I question this part:  `new SolidBrush(animalColor)`

Since this is neither deliberately given a `Dispose` nor is it wrapped in a `using`, I assume this is also an example of poor form, since the `SolidBrush` object will be created and never disposed.

I have always labored under the assumption that I must use one of the aforementioned disposal mechanisms directly, or risk a memory leak.

Am I correct, or is there some deeper implicit disposal going on of which I am unaware? Perhaps because it was never assigned to a variable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is another example of a bad code example from MSDN.  Their examples are rife with undisposed objects.

Comment: Plenty of .NET programmers have written code like this for *years* and never realized that disposing it can be important.  They'll easily get away with it, it is a very short-lived object and the next gen# 0 GC and finalizer pass releases it.  Until they start to tinker with Bitmap, then it gets to hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be inside a `using` statement or it should explicitly call `Dispose`, **but**,

`SolidBrush` class inherits `Brush` class which has a destructor/finalize defined as:

Source from [here:](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Brush.cs,132)

```
   /**
     * Object cleanup
     */
    /// <include file='doc\Brush.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Brush.Finalize"]/*' />
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       Releases memory allocated for this <see cref='System.Drawing.Brush'/>.
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    ~Brush() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

Once your object of class `SolidBrush` goes out of scope, *Ultimately* its destructor will be called. At that point `Dispose` will be called releasing *any* unmangaged resources.

See: [Destructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

> The destructor implicitly calls Finalize on the base class of the
>   object.

The **only issue with relying on destructor/finalizer** is, that, you can't predict when the object will finally be disposed.

Comment: "The only issue with relying on destructor/finalizer is, that, you can't predict when the object will finally be disposed." - Which could be a big problem considering these objects are typically created in an `OnPaint` handler, which may be called many times very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I should say that's a poor example from msdn. You ought to `Dispose` it; no object will be disposed automatically.

It is not necessarily a leak, `Brush` implements a `Finalizer` which will `Dispose` it when garbage collected but you shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: This object will ultimately be disposed, because it implements a finalizer that ensures disposal.  See @Habib's answer.  One could not know that however without checking the source code, and of course some implementations of .NET may be different.

Comment: @EricJ. I already mentioned that in my answer. What difference you see in habib's answer? Also do note that finalizers won't run always.

Answer (score 0):

As with all managed objects, it is automatically freed. This is a key aspect to understand about .NET and C#.

However, it might not be done in a timely manner. And since this object is using a system resource, I do not in fact consider this to be an example of good form.

Comment: I don't think there is any API-level guarantee that unmanaged resources are also released, though a reasonable implementation would do so.

Comment: It will not be automatically *disposed*. It will be *finalized* if it has a finalizer (and becomes eligible for garbage collection), but that's not the same as being disposed.

Comment: Where did I say that there was a guarantee that *unmanaged resources* are released? I am talking about managed objects. And, yes, any reasonable implementation will hopefully take care of any unmanaged resources.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Doesn't any reasonable implementation perform any dispose action when the object is released? Are you saying the code above would *never* release the system brush object?

Comment: @JonathanWood: Jon's comment is aimed at your terminology.  A reasonable implementation of an object that holds an unmanaged or scarce resource will provide a finalizer to ensure that resource is ultimately released, whether or not the programmer called IDisposable.Dispose().  That is different than "disposing" the object.

Comment: @EricJ.: Yes, I caught that I used that term there and have already changed that.

Comment: No - it's the other way round. `Dispose()` usually does whatever the finalizer does and possibly more; there can easily be things that are done by disposing of a resource which *aren't* done on finalization. Even leaving that aside, I find it important to use the right terminology to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

That object should be disposed, yes.

That said it is a valid course of action not to dispose certain light-weight objects if it would be really inconvenient to do so. `Task` is a prime example. A `SolidColorBrush` in WPF is probably rather light. If you are sure not to "leak" too many of them this code is OK.

Keep in mind that adding a mechanism for disposal here (e.g. `using`) would clutter the code. That's clearly a (small) disadvantage to doing so.